# Lightspeed - what do we measure? Wave group, phase, front and signal velocities

Tags: experimental-physics, speed-of-light, phase-velocity

I'm studying for an experiment of measuring the lightspeed c. It will be measured following the rotating mirrors method by Fizeau-Foucault, using a HeNe laser.

I could understand - and visualize - the difference between phase, group and front velocities, in Wikipedia have some good stuff.

But there is some confusion about what I am actually going to measure. I have some questions about the interpretations. In order of importance:

1 - My interpretation is that I am going to measure the front velocity. Is that correct?

2 - In some cases, front and group velocity can be the same? Is this my case?

3 - The other velocities also exist in this experiment? In specific cases, like plane waves, we can't talk about group velocity, for example, but I don't know if it is like that in this experiment.

4 - What is the difference between front and signal velocity? I can visualize and find animated diagrams about the first, but not about the last one.

5 - Information is transported by front or by signal velocity?

Thank you in advance